# Discord bot website, how to get Guild count

Tags: javascript, web, discord

I want to make a website for my discord bot. On that website i want to include the total server, member, and channel count. Is it possible to do that without using PHP or any backend stuff? (So just with Javascript, connected with script tags) if i do need PHP that could also be ok. But the best will be with JavaScript

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7H4T.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i ended up doing:

I made a project with google firebase and added a firestore database.
I made reading public and writing private. I connected the website to the firestore database just by using vanilla javascript. (After retrieving data i used InnerHTML to insert it to the website)

In my bot's script i added some stuff so it posts the info from the bot to the database.